# Oracle ODBC x64 - getting 0 when selecting a number(9) column

Tags: .net, oracle, odbc, 64-bit

I'm having a really weird problem with a third party web service that uses an ODBC connection to Oracle 10.2.0.3.0. I've written a .NET client that generates the same SQL as the web service so I can find out what's going on.
The web service is hosted by IIS 6 that's in x64 mode so we use Oracle x64 client.

The oracle client version is 10.2.0.1.0.

I have a table that looks like this (I've removed some columns and names):

```
SQL> describe tablename;

 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 KOD                                                VARCHAR2(30)
 ORDNING                                            NUMBER(5)
 AVGIFT                                             NUMBER(9)
```

I then in SQL*Plus issue the following statement:

```
SELECT KOD as kod, AVGIFT as riskPoang
FROM tablename Where upper(KODTYP) = 'OBJLIVSV_RISKVERKSAMTYP' ORDER BY ORDNING
```

And I get the following result:

```
KOD                             RISKPOANG
------------------------------ ----------
Hög risk                               55
Mellan risk                            35
Låg risk                               15
Mycket låg risk                         5
```

But when I execute the exact same SQL using the same DSN on the same machine I get this:

```
Values
Kod: Hög risk           RiskPoäng: 0
Kod: Mellan risk        RiskPoäng: 0
Kod: Låg risk           RiskPoäng: 0
Kod: Mycket låg risk    RiskPoäng: 0
```

If I first cast the number to varchar and then back again to number, like this:

```
SELECT KOD as kod, to_number(to_char(AVGIFT, '99'), '9999999999') as riskPoang
FROM tablename Where upper(KODTYP) = 'OBJLIVSV_RISKVERKSAMTYP' ORDER BY ORDNING
```

I get the correct result:

```
Values
Kod: Hög risk           RiskPoäng: 55
Kod: Mellan risk        RiskPoäng: 35
Kod: Låg risk           RiskPoäng: 15
Kod: Mycket låg risk    RiskPoäng: 5
```

Has anyone else experiences this? It's incredibly annoying and I'm completely stuck and not sure what to do next. We have a third party web service that use these tables so I must get the original SQL-statement to work since I can't modify its code.

And pointers are greatly appreciated! :-)

Best regards,
Mats

Comment: I agree ODBC *should* work, but have you looked at ODP.NET?

Comment: Yeah we use it for another project and it works great. Problem is that the third party web service we bought can't be changed... 
The .NET client I've written simply executes the same SQL as the web service. I wrote it so I can see what happens.

Comment: The problem may be in the .NET data access code. Please show how your `OdbcCommand` and `OdbcParameter` objects are initialized and used.

Comment: It uses a string containing a SQL-statement and then creates an OdbcCommand from that. It then uses an OdbcDataAdapter to fill a table. Not really best practice, but it's a third party system and I have no control over it. Btw, I just figured out that it's vulnerable to SQL-injection. >:)

Answer (score 0):

Bah, it was an Oracle bug. :-(

I figured it had something to do with the Oracle Client but I couldn't find any information about it. Finally found this page on oracle forum: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=862588

The bug is number 5128512 and is fixed in patch level 10204.

Hopefully this can be of help to someone else.